# Select different country mirror than "locale"

Tags: system-installation, mirrors

Good day,

I'm installing Ubuntu instances in Germany or France datacenters, but with the locale/etc. set for South Africa. Now the (hyper intelligent) Ubuntu installer (contrary to the Debian installer) doesn't allow me to set the mirror/country to use for the package downloads, which makes the installations quite slow (other than setting up a mirror myself and point every installation to that one, but that would be cumbersome for various reasons)

SO, how do I tell the installer to let me pick the mirror I want to use contrary to my locale/country settings?

Comment: Yes... should be marked duplicate ;(

Answer (score 0):

you can install ubuntu without using updates and after installation change mirrors in /etc/apt/sources.list or update-manager and you can use update-locale and locale-gen fr_FR fr_FR.UTF-8 as expemple to change your settings.

Comment: Doesn't help, I guess the answer is then: "Sorry, can't be done at installation time, installation of ubuntu servers are only to be done by id-ten-t personnel"?